# Nested Mixins LESS parse error

Tags: css, less, mixins

I'm looking to do this. But I get a parse error. Is this possible with LESS?

Mixin:

```
.fa-icon(@fa-pseudo-postion, @fa-icon, @fa-font-size, @fa-display-value) {
  &:@{fa-pseudo-postion} {
    content: @fa-icon;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: @fa-font-size;
    display: @fa-display-value;
  }
}
```

In Use:

```
.fa-icon(before, @fa-plus, 16px, inline);
```

Comment: This is a known item with respect to usage of pseudo selectors in selector interpolation. [This](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1294) issue thread from the official Less GitHub page would help you.

Comment: Thanks, I used the workaround in [that](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1294) issue to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround until [this bug](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1294) is fixed.

```
.fa-icon(@fa-pseudo-position, @fa-icon, @fa-font-size, @fa-display-value) {

  @pseudo-position: ~":@{fa-pseudo-position}"; // Workaround for this bug (https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1294) remove when fixed

  &@{pseudo-position} {
    content: @fa-icon;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: @fa-font-size;
    display: @fa-display-value;
  }
}
```